# How to fix document append child slowing down react program?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, performance, appendchild

I am attempting to make an incremental game similar to Cookie Clicker in React. I have added the click animation below for when the main button is clicked. This item is created as a div and appended as a child to the root of the button display area. The problem is that by doing so, it creates a delay between when the user is allowed to click again due to the slow processing time. I have removed the animation and the response time stays the same.

Is there any changes i could make to speed this process up?

GrowButton.scss

```
#growIcon {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 245px;
  height: 245px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #263238;
  background-color: #263238;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

#growRoot {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 350px;
  height: 47.8vh;

  > [id^="x"] {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    animation: GoUp 1s forwards linear;
    -moz-animation: GoUp 1s forwards linear;
    -webkit-animation: GoUp 1s forwards linear;
    -o-animation: GoUp 1s forwards linear;
    -ms-animation: GoUp 1s forwards linear;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes GoUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes GoUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes GoUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes GoUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes GoUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

GrowButton.js

```
  buttonClick(event, props) {
    props.onclick();
    let growRoot = document.getElementById("growRoot");
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.innerText = x;
    newDiv.setAttribute("id", "x" + x++);
    newDiv.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
    newDiv.style.left = event.clientX - 10 + "px";
    growRoot.appendChild(newDiv);
  }

   <div id="growRoot">
       <img
            onClick={(e) => this.buttonClick(e, this.props)}
            id="growIcon"
            src="./Images/Plague_Icon_3.png"
            alt="Dummy growIcon"
        />
    < /div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  your component state keep track of all elements

elements is an array [] of html elements

on button click push a new element to that array

in render function you need to loop elements array and render each element

I use functional component to demonstrate this, you should be able to adapt it to your needs.

```
const test = () => {
const [elements, setElements] = useState([<div> Some Element You Want Rendered </div>]);

return (
<div id="growRoot">
       <img
            onClick={(e) => {
                 const element = document.createElement("div");
                 element.innerText = x;
                 element.setAttribute("id", "x" + x++);
                 element.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
                 element.style.left = event.clientX - 10 + "px";
                 setElements([...elements].concat([element]))
             }}
            id="growIcon"
            src="./Images/Plague_Icon_3.png"
            alt="Dummy growIcon"
        />
       {elements.map(element => element)} 
</div>
)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended using something along the lines of             
setElements((prevArray) => [
              ...prevArray,
              <div
                id="growClickAnimation"
                style={{ top: event.clientY - 25, left: event.clientX - 15 }}
              >
                +{prettyNumber(props.growPerClick)}
              </div>,
            ]);

Comment: Your welcome please accept this answer if it helped answer your question